# how to add id to pre element only if li element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a piece of code on my forum which is all in a pre tag. 
Each comment is posted in a li tag with a unique id. 
I inherit this id and add it to the pre tag with some addition.
This works fine.
Just the first discussion start; this pre element is not in a li tag but is part of a div with also a unique id.
So what i want to achieve: check if a list tag exists and bind the closest li id to the pre tag. 
If closest li tag does not exist (discussion start), look for the closest div id and bind that to the pre tag:

in code:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
        if ($('li').length > 0) { 
          $(this).attr('id', $(this).closest('li').attr('id')+'_pre');
          }
          else {
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).closest('div').attr('id')+'_pre');
          }
        });
```

But when i look into the source, i can see for the first pre tag which says:

```
id="undefined_pre"
```

is this not the correctcode i produced for it?

Comment: please give that html structure.. so it will be more clear

Comment: because your li doesn't have id attribute

Comment: very hard to answer as there is no relative markup as per your js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('pre').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).closest('li, div').first().attr('id')+'_pre');
});
```